# Baresip with android

Tags: android, android-ndk, sip, baresip

I'm a beginner in NDK. So, I want to implement SIP to android use Baresip  - [Git page](https://github.com/alfredh/baresip-android)

I followed the step on Git page, now my project have "jni" folder with 4 libraries: re, rem, openssl and baresip.

Anyone suggest me an idea with Android.mk file to build those libraries to project?

Answer (score 2):

for those who coming to this later, this is a sample for using Baresip on Android:
https://github.com/MobiSciLab/Baresip-DemoAudioCall

Answer (score 0):

You need to build `libbaresip.so`. Afterwards, you'll need to create a C JNI wrapper to call baresip functions from Java code.